# Django-models cannot import Modelform

Tags: django-models

In views.py is : from django.forms import Modelform. Still i get the Importerror. I read the other post. What am i doing wrong? And how to solve it?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.forms import Modelform
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from mytool.forms import Modelform

class Search(models.Model):
    search = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Modelform
from mytool.models import Search

class SearchForm(model.Modelform):
        search = forms.CharField(label ='search', max_length=250, required=True)
        subject = forms.CharField(label ='subject', max_length=150, required=False)
        user = forms.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=forms.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
                model = Search
                fields = ('search', 'subject', 'user',)
```

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import TemplateView
    from .forms import SearchForm

Comment: If i delete in forms.py "from django import forms" it is not solved

Comment: Not relevant anymore. Thanks